# Left bracket not matched correctly while using lambda inside brackets, inside template function

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-c++-2013

**Using Visual C++ 2013, the following code produces a weird compile error:**

```
/// header.h
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename Func>
    void operator[](Func f)
    {
        f();
    }
};

template <typename T>
void funct()
{
    Test t;
    t[[](){; }];    // line 16 // The same error with t[ ([](){; }) ];
}

/// main.cpp
int main()
{
    funct<int>();
    // funct();
}
```

**Errors:**

```
1>c:\path\to\header.h(16): error C2958: the left bracket '[' found at 'e:\path\to\header.h(16)' was not matched correctly
1>c:\path\to\header.h(16): error C2059: syntax error : ']'
1>c:\path\to\header.h(17): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>c:\path\to\header.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

**This error does not happen when the lambda function body doesn't have any statements:**

```
template <typename T>
void funct()
{
    Test t;
    t[[](){ }];    // line 16 // No semicolon - No statement - No errors
}
```

**Or when the function is not template:**

```
// Ordinary function - No errors
void funct()
{
    Test t;
    t[[](){; }];    // line 16
}
```

I think I have found a bug in this compiler. However, if anyone knows a way to write this without errors and without using a variable to hold the lambda function, that would be great.

Comment: Tried before. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VC++ correctly rejects this code, but for the wrong reasons - it's a bug. It's ill-formed according to [dcl.attr.grammar]/6:

> Two consecutive left square bracket tokens shall appear only when
>   introducing an *attribute-specifier*. [ *Note:*
>   If two consecutive left square brackets appear where an attribute-specifier is not allowed, **the program is
>   ill-formed even if the brackets match an alternative grammar production.** *— end note* ] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int p[10];
> void f() {
>     int x = 42, y[5];
>     int(p[[x] { return x; }()]); // error: invalid attribute on a nested
>                                  // declarator-id and not a 
>                                  // function-style cast of an element of p.
>
>     y[[] { return 2; }()] = 2; // error even though attributes are not allowed
>                                // in this context.
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

So try enclosing the lambda-expression in two parantheses as follows.

```
t[ ([](){; }) ];
```

Or write

```
auto&& closure = [](){; };
t[closure]; // move here if correct value category is desired
```

Comment: @MeenaAlfons Then introduce an intermediate object to hold the closure object. It's just another VC++ bug :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that VC2013 doesn't support attributes, so, oddly enough, the OP's code is ill-formed for a reason unrelated to the error they are seeing :)

Comment: @Columbo your answer is perfect in terms of the standard but I think it would be better to add your comment "It's just another VC++ bug" or T.C.'s comment that VC2013 doesn't support attributes to well define this situation as a bug also. Thank you for introducing attributes to me :).